# How can I print to the Visual Studio Code console in Portuguese?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, console

I'm trying to print to the console a Portuguese name. Now, I need some particular encoding but I just can't make it work.

The code is the following:

```
name = "João".encode().decode("latin_1")
print(name)
```

I know Python 3 already decodes to utf-8, so I tried to decode it to latin_1. However, with no success. I just can't make it print the way I defined it. I already tried cp860 and cp1252, but it leads to the same problem.

The output of the previous code is:

```
Jo├â┬úo
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: One of your comments indicates that this is related to your IDE, please share all relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

you should write your code like this

```
name = "João".encode('latin_1').decode("latin_1")
print(name)
```

while encoding the encoding type should also be mentioned otherwise it will default encoding which is `UTF-8`

Comment: The problem seems to be from Visual Studio Code, since with the command line, it just prints correctly without any encode/decode. I just can't make it work on Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do any encoding or decoding of the string in Python 3 for it to work with printing to your terminal as Python already knows what your terminal's encoding is and strings are already Unicode so it implicitly encodes it for you.

Executing the following from VS Code on Windows 10:

```py
name = "João"
print(name)
```

leads to:

```
João
```